# Visualizar ultimo registro en input en controlador asp core mvc

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Estoy realizando un formulario de registro para la creación de un paciente pero uno de los campos que requiero es el código que debe visualizarse al momento del registro.

```
 public void OnGet()
    {
        var ultimoPaciente = _context.TBL_PACIENTE.OrderByDescending(x =>
        x.PAC_CODIGO).FirstOrDefault(); <-- ERROR
      

        MODEL_PACIENTE = new PACIENTE
        {

            Genero_Lista = _lPacienteGen.GetGenero(_context),
            Comuna_Lista = _lComuna.GetComuna(_context),
            Odontologo_Lista = _lOdontologo.GetOdontologo(_context)
        }; 
    }
```

Estoy tratando de cargar el ultimo registro pero al cargar la pagina me arroja el sgte error.

```
SqlException: Invalid column name 'ErrorMessage'.
```

Mi clase paciente

```
     public class MODELO_PACIENTE
    {
        #region TBL_PACIENTE
        [Key]
        public int PAC_ID { get; set; }

        public String PAC_CODIGO { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Nombre del Paciente es Obligatorio.")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Solo se Permiten Letras")]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre(S) Paciente")]
        public String PAC_NOMBRE { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Apellido del Paciente es Obligatorio.")]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Solo se Permiten Letras")]
        [Display(Name = "Apellido(S) Paciente")]
        public String PAC_APELLIDO { get; set; }

        public String PAC_SEXO { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "El RUT es Obligatorio")]
        [RegularExpression("(^[0-9]+$)", ErrorMessage = "Solo se Permiten Números")]
        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "El RUT solo permite 10 dígitos")]
        public String PAC_RUT { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:dd-MM-yyyyy}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime PAC_FECHA_NAC { get; set; }

        public int PAC_EDAD { get; set; }

        public String PAC_REPRESENTANTE { get; set; }

        public String PAC_DIRECCION { get; set; }

        public String PAC_COMUNA { get; set; }

        public String PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS { get; set; }

        public String PAC_TELEFONO { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Email es Obligatorio.")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "No es una Dirección de Correo válida")]
        public String PAC_CORREO { get; set; }

        public String PAC_CONVENIO { get; set; }

        public String PAC_PREVISIONES { get; set; }

        public String PAC_OBSERVACIONES { get; set; }

        public String PAC_COD_ODONT { get; set; }

        public byte[] PAC_IMAGEN { get; set; }

        public DateTime PAC_FEC_REG { get; set; }

        public DateTime PAC_FEC_ACT { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        #endregion
}
```

En mi controlador esta es la linea de código que debería cargar ese código pero como lo puedo colocar?

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>COD Paciente:</label>
      <input asp-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_CODIGO" type="number" placeholder="COD PAC." class="form-control" autofocus />
      <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PACIENTE.PAC_CODIGO" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
```

Si alguien me podría guiar o ayudar que debo colocar le agradezco mucho.

Comment: segun entiendo lo que le estas mandando con el modelo es un string?

Comment: Si efectivamente trato de enviar un tipo string que contiene 00001 por ejemplo, pero me arroja ese error